# Java 8 Nashorn JJS – javascript console

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

a question to an expert:
The latest Java 8 provides Javascript engine Nashorn. Its known that with the magic of invokedynamic the  javascript is compiled to JVM bytecode, unlike Mozilla Rhino, which just interprets it.

But what about JJS (javascript console). Is there any compilation on the fly? Or there is just interpretation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jjs` is just the name of a command-line tool, distributed with the JDK, that invokes Nashorn.

See [the Java Platform Tools Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jjs.html) for details.

Comment: So am I right telling this: I run jjs, the jjs itself somehow starts nashorn and I get the console; I type in something, for example "new Date()" and press enter; whats happening inside(?) – nashorn generates bytecode of the "new Date()" construction, pushes it through the JVM, then halt the jvm for the next user input? Is that it?

Comment: It is an oversimplification to say Nashorn "generates bytecode." In the case you specify, Nashorn evaluates your code and as a result creates a new JavaScript Date object (implemented by a Nashorn Java class). The "bytecode" part for Nashorn is, roughly, that the JVM now contains instructions that allow methods to be dynamically attached to Java objects, which supports dynamic typing for languages like JavaScript. Nashorn uses those instructions rather than synthesizing a whole method invocation layer on top of Java, which is what was needed before `invokedynamic` (the new JVM instruction).

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understanding now!